# Itunes crashing even after reinstallation

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes

I access songs from bootcamp drive. All of a sudden, itunes took approx 20mins to open in macbook. Every action like playing a song took a huge time and finally it crashed. I get this when i right click the app "Application not responding".

I uninstalled and then reinstalled it. It worked fine for a week. Now the crashing has started again when I tried to play an ALAC format song.

I can't keep reinstalling itunes everytime I want to play songs.

I dont think the problem is with the library being in a different disk because itunes creates a copy in Macbook drive inside the "itunes media" folder.

Please help me with this serious bug.

Comment: Your first & last paragraphs are conflicting. If you access your media on another drive, then it's not in iTunes Media [or vice versa]

Answer (score 1):

Try to open your iTunes in safe mode ,(restart and hold shift) then started iTunes just fine. This same issue i had . 
If this didn't solved can please post the crash report of the iTunes , when its occurring again.